# C++ MFC combobox scroll bar events

Tags: c++, scroll, combobox, mfc

In MFC I would like to be able to set the number of lines a CComboBox scrolls when you mouse click above or below the scroll bar thumb.

That's it!

Comment: Why do you want to change the Default behaviour. It is exactly 1 page of items that is scrolled.

Answer (score 1):

When the Combobox drops down (`CBN_DROPDOWN` message), call [GetComboBoxInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb775939(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine the handle of the list control. Now you can call [GetScrollInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787583(v=vs.85).aspx). Get the page parameter and set a new one with [SetScrollInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787595(v=vs.85).aspx).

The problem is, that this scrollbar parameters are automatically set by the system, when the size and the number of member changes.

If this has no effect, because CBN_DROPDOWN is to early you can just post a message to yourself (POstMessage), that performs this action when the message pump fetches your message.

Comment: Thank you for the help I will let you know how I get on.